# How to solve this problem ? file path woo-razorpay/razorpay-sdk/Razorpay.php

Tags: wordpress

```
Warning:Constant REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS already defined in public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-razorpay/razorpay-sdk/Razorpay.php on line 4
```

In this file I found this code on line: 4

```
const REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS = true;
```

How to solve this frontend error?

Comment: thnq sir i edit this question kindly help me I'm new show i don't know how to post to question

Comment: Disable the plugin "woo-razorpay".

Comment: thnq solved to my problem it's workings

Answer (score 0):

Update your woo razorpay SDK file with latest version razor.php
[Latest code](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-woocommerce/blob/master/razorpay-sdk/Razorpay.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sonam’s answer sounds like a good idea, but, as stated in the comments, a rigid way that actually worked in this case is to deactivate the plugin ‘woo-razorpay’. Not sure what the actual name is in the plugin section of WordPress, but probably ‘Razorpay for Woocommerce’ or something like that.

In case you really need this plugin: the error states that a constant is defined twice. The whole idea of a constant is that it cannot be redefined. So, what you can do is:

1. Try updating the plugin to a newer version if there exists one. The makers might have fixed this for you already.
2. Find out - with a file content search - where the first definition of this constant was done and update that plugin or theme.
3. Contact the makers of the plugin and see if they can fix the problem in a next update of their plugin.
4. If all that doesn’t help change the code in the file specified in the warning:

   ```
   if(!defined(REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS){
       const REQUESTS_SILENCE_PSR0_DEPRECATIONS = true:
   }
   ```

   But keep in mind that when you update the plugin this change will be overwritten and you will have to do it again.

What you can also do is disable WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php. This might stop the warning from appearing. Or use the php error_reporting function with E_ALL & ~E_WARNING so you will see error messages but not warnings like this one.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING)
```